# Does the ー represent a double vowel or a long vowel sound?

Tags: katakana, vowels, long-vowels

For words like パーティー (party), I know ー is doubling the ア and イ. But for a word like センセイ (and let's assume for the sake of argument that it is regularly spelled in katakana), would it be センセイ or センセー ?

Comment: Do not know if duplicate of http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5548/what-are-the-rules-determining-the-use-of-the-dash-in-katakana .

Comment: The title does not match the main text in the question.

Comment: I don't understand. I was under the impression that センセイ and センセー sound completely different..

Comment: @Chris How so? Even written in hiragana, you wouldn't explicitly pronounce the い。You would pronounce えい as if it was ええ. I am under the impression that regardless of whether or not it is written in hiragana or katakana that rule still holds.

Comment: @dotnetN00b: I understand that you "can" pronounce the えい as ええ, but where is the rule that you "cannot" pronounce them differently?

Comment: @Chris The rule that changes ei to ee is an **obligatory** rule (with some restrictions).

Comment: @Sawa: Is that referencing the "native Japanese words that do not have elongated vowel sounds" portion of Matt's post from http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5548/what-are-the-rules-determining-the-use-of-the-dash-in-katakana ?

Answer (score 6):

The fact is, 先生 is not regularly written in katakana in the first place, so **there is no authentic guideline that tells you which is correct**. If you are going to write it in katakana, there must be an unusual purpose for doing it. If that purpose is to indicate that you just don't/can't use kanji, then センセイ would be appropriate. If the purpose is that you wanted to make it look like it is pronounced by a foreigner or a robot, then センセー might be more appropriate.

Comment: Is there an unofficial guideline/rule, colloquialism, or normal-everyday pattern?

Comment: @dotnetN00b You do not seem to understand my answer.

Comment: Well, I guess not.