# Is the "wa-particle" in katakana ワ or ハ？

Tags: katakana, orthography, particle-は

Is the "wa-particle" in katakana ワ or ハ？

(Just a quick question - I think I have seen both used, but if ワ is correct then I have just seen the results of a computer o/p automatically using ハ)

Comment: how could ワ be correct seriously ?

Comment: This is probably obvious, but in the modern orthography in Japanese, particles are written in hiragana.  So if a particle is written in katakana, there is a special reason for it (say, the author wants to make the text hard to read), and all the rules might be thrown away because of that reason.

Comment: Related: [Does the ー　represent a double vowel or a long vowel sound?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5939)  (The title is unclear, but the linked question is about the usage of katakana in words which are not usually written in katakana.)

Comment: This also is probably obvious, but there are both particles は and わ, both pronounce as _wa_.  Hyperworm is writing about the former (topic marker).

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: I think first Japanese character set encoded for computers could only produce katakana (see JIS X 0201 in wikipedia), which is why (I think) we still see them on utility bills and any narrative inserted would be in katakan.

Comment: @oldergod: My misunderstanding probably comes from seeing japanese typed in roman letters and converted for whatever reason by a computer katakana (the "wa" would appear as ワ).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

ハ for the topic particle. There's no difference from hiragana.

Answer (score 18):

The basic answer is that は is written ハ in katakana.

---

However, I think it depends on *why* it's written in katakana.  One reason you might write something in katakana is to communicate pronunciation, and in this case the particle は would be written ワ:

```
  spelling        pronunciation

  おはよう         オハヨー
  こんにちは       コンニチワ
```

You can see this sort of use of katakana in [some official documents](https://www.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/sisaku/joho/joho/kijun/naikaku/gendaikana/huhyo_kyo.html), for example.

On the other hand, if you're just writing regular Japanese using katakana, you'd usually spell は as ハ.  Another reason you might use katakana is for the *use-mention distinction*; some books or papers about Japanese grammar, for instance, write particles in katakana when they're mentioned rather than used, and in this context は would be ハ (and を would be ヲ, and so on).

Answer (score 13):

You can see it's **ハ** as what the old MS office assistant *F1* said

[image: F1 Japanese office assistant]

You can also see the usage of **ヲ** in the above sentence

---

As a side note the text above isn't a translation of the English version

[image: F1 English office assistant]

Unfortunately F1 is the only one who *talks* in Katakana. Here are the other [Japanese assistants](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/akaibara/20130815) and [English assistants](https://menga.net/bring-back-earl-the-cat)

Comment: +1 I don't know what that googly-eyed thing is but it's way more adorable than the paperclip.

Answer (score -1):

Katakana is just used for foreign words, the grammar elements are not written in Katakana.

Comment: Katakana is *not* just used for foreign words. Yes, nowadays we use it for almost only loanwords, but this custom is relatively new. Here are images in a textbook before WWII  http://gastrocamera.cocolog-nifty.com/blog/2009/01/11/index.html

Comment: Textbooks published in taisho period use katakana for japanese and hirakana for foreign languages. For exmaple http://kindai.ndl.go.jp/info:ndljp/pid/1133275/9?tocOpened=1 第二章第四節「ふぇるまーノ定理」