# How did 沢山 (たくさん) come to mean "many"?

Tags: kanji, etymology, adjectives

There are understandably a lot of words in Japanese that are made of Kanji totally unrelated to the meaning of the actual word.

However, it's hard to ignore the ubiquitous 沢山.

How did a combination of swamp and mountain come to be used to express "many"?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/42374/9831 (#5), https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/2981/9831 (#2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 語源由来辞典 (http://gogen-allguide.com/) has the following [entry for 沢山](http://gogen-allguide.com/ta/takusan.html)

> **沢山**
>
> 【意味】 沢山とは、数量の多いこと。十分なこと。それ以上不要なこと。
>
> 【沢山の語源・由来】
> たくさんは、多い意味の形容動詞語幹「さは（多）」と、数の多いことを表す「やま（山）」を重ねた「さはやま」に「沢山」の字を当て、音読したものといわれる。
> ただし、「さはやま（さわやま）」の例が見られるのは近世に入ってからであるのに対し、「たくさん」の例は鎌倉時代の『平家物語』に見られるため、「さはやま」は「沢山（たくさん）」の訓読みと考えるのが妥当である。
> その他、「たかい（高い）」「たける（長ける）」など、「ｔａｋ」の音から「たく（沢）」が当てられ「沢山」になったとする説もあるが未詳。

Summarized the entry says that the word 沢山 is often said to be the *on'yomi* of さわやま (=さはやま), where

- 沢【さわ】 is *ateji* for the word stem さは (多) meaning "many", and
- 山【やま】 is also used for its meaning of "many, numerous".

However, さはやま only appears in the early modern period, whereas there are already examples of たくさん in the *Heike Monogatari* from the Kamakura period, so さはやま could rather be thought of a *kun'yomi* of たくさん.

The first part could also come from *tak-* in words like *takai* (高い) "tall" or *takeru* (長ける) "to rise high", but in the end, the origin is just not clear.

Comment: IMO it’s literally 多 “having the meaning ‘many’(多い)” rather than “various meanings”.

Comment: @Igor Yes, thank you, that was careless on my part.

Comment: I have wondered often about the origin of this kanji, and just assumed it was ateji. Thank you @Earthliŋ for your erudite explanation.