# "筆順" sounds more scientific / formal than "書き順"?

Tags: word-choice

I just read the word "筆順" in an article about linguistics. I'd never seen this word before. I've always said "書き順" for "stroke order".

"書き順" is the natural way to say "stroke order" in daily conversation?
"筆順" is the natural way to write about "stroke order" in a more scientific discussion about linguistics?

Not a big deal. I am just curious.

Comment: Related, maybe?? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23156/9831

Comment: @Chocolate I've no idea. But, I do know that 音 readings are more "formal" than 訓 readings.  Things indigenous to Japan are usually read with 訓. So, I'm gonna guess that I am correct. You only pull-out 筆順 when you want to sound formal. And since I can't read Japanese, that is why I've never seen "筆順" before.

Answer (score 1):

- 会話では「筆順」ではなく、「書き順」を使います。
  同様に「どんな順序で書く」とも言います。「書き順」と「どんな順序で書く」とは大変違うようですが、次のようにいずれも使います。例えば「この字、**どんな順序で書く**の？　縦棒が先？　それとも横棒？」⇔「この字の**書き順**は？　縦棒が先？　それとも横棒？」あるいは、「この字、**どんな順序で書く**のか教えて。」⇔「この字の**書き順**教えて。」
- scientific discussionに限らず、文章の中で書くときは基本的に「筆順」を使います。もし、「書き順」と書くと、子供が書いた文章か、教養がない人が書いたように見えます。